# Getting the average of not null fields

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, vb.net, crystal-reports

I'm using Crystal reports in my application

```
average({ConsultationDetail.viandenord} )
```

I need to get the avearge of not null field `viandenord`

1. How can i change the formula to get this result?
2. What is the best way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below code.

```
If(ISNULL({ConsultationDetail.viandenord}))
Then //Your code
Else average({ConsultationDetail.viandenord} )
```

Edit:.......................................................................................
Assuming you have placed your fields in detail section:

1. Create formula `@sum` and place below code in the detail and take `sum` of the field.

   ```
   If(ISNULL({ConsultationDetail.viandenord}))
   Then //Your code
   Else {ConsultationDetail.viandenord}
   ```
2. To calculate count create formula `@count` and write below code and place it after the `@sum` in detail section.

   ```
     if {ConsultationDetail.viandenord}=0
    then 0
   else 1
   ```
3. Now take sum of the formula `@count`
4. To calculate `Average`

   ```
    Sum({ConsultationDetail.viandenord})/Sum(@count)
   ```

Above code is just an example.. Let me know how it goes

Comment: no it didn't work :(  i have no code if the value of the field equal zero, i need just to count the average of the not null cells

Comment: didn't get you can you elaborate

Comment: you are trying to get average if the filed is `notnull`, is that correct? Also is it throwing any error?

Comment: yes if i had as values 1 , 2 and 0 ==> the average must be 1.5 not 1

Comment: ok you don't want to count that entry where value is `0`.. In this case `Average` doesn't work.. you need to calculate the `sum` separately and `count` separately and then do as `Sum/count`. Let me know where do you placed the fields in the report?

Comment: can i explain with a snippet plz?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51420/discussion-between-lamloumi-and-siva)